# how to reset method in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file

I have a form that uploads many files and images at the same time.
the problem is this method

```
$this->upload->display_errors()
```

each time the loop goes through this method it saves error from the previous loop round

```
$error[$i]= "File error: ".$this->upload->display_errors();
```

for example, if I uploaded two illegal files it shows me this

index 0: file is not allowed
index 1: file is not allowed file is not allowed

So how can I reset this method? 
ps: I tried to reset() function and it didn't work

***UPDATE***
This is the method

```
          public function do_upload($product_id)
        {
            $error = array();

            if(isset($_FILES['files']['name'])&&!empty($_FILES['files']['name'][0])):

         for ($i=0; $i <count($_FILES['files']['name']) ; $i++) :


                $config['upload_path']          = './images/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 1;



                $this->load->library('upload', $config);





              $_FILES['files[]']['name'] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
              $_FILES['files[]']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
              $_FILES['files[]']['size'] = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];

               if(!$this->upload->do_upload('files[]')){


 $error[$i]= "File name: ". $_FILES['files']['name'][$i] ." ". $this->upload->display_errors() ."<br>";

               }else{

              $files = $this->upload->data();

$data = array('file_name'=>$files['file_name'],'product_id'=>$product_id,'file_type'=>$files['file_type']);

               $this->Files_model->create_file($data);
               }





endfor;








  endif;
 return $error;
//end method
        }
```

Comment: show some more details, code where u have this

Comment: why someone downvotes this question? This is not the best question but good enough to be here!

Comment: Can you please show us the loop?

Comment: The problem with CodeIgniter file upload is that it doesn't handle multiple file uploads particularly well like this. The only suggestion I can make is that you loop over the $_FILES super global and process each image one at a time with CodeIgniter, then store each file upload error in a master error array.... I hope this makes sense

Comment: webCode.ie am already doing this

Comment: Wow that formatting ... Take a second and make it look somewhat readable

Answer (score 1):

We can't reset $this->upload->do_upload();

But we can reinitialize like that

```
// first upload 
$this->config->load('upload');
-- Code to upload Here -- 

// Another file
$this->config->load('upload_other_files');
-- Code to upload Here --
```

OR You can defined multiple config array for each file Like below code :

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '100';
$config['max_width'] = '1024';
$config['max_height'] = '768';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

For another files

```
$config2['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config2['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config2['max_size'] = '100';
$config2['max_width'] = '100';
$config2['max_height'] = '100';

$this->load->library('upload', $config2);

// Alternately you can set
$this->upload->initialize($config2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset (errors) like this:

```
$this->upload->error_msg = [];

...do_upload
```